# Marcar ponto em imagem obtida pelo sensor do Kinect

Tags: c#, wpf, kinect

Galera, estou com a seguinte problemática: tenho uma aplicação que me fornece as imagens do Kinect em tempo real, só que eu preciso desenvolver uma funcionalidade em que o usuário marque alguns pontos na imagem utilizando o mouse. Com os pontos marcados, preciso obter as coordenada X, Y e Z de cada ponto marcado. O meu problema, é que não tenho ideia de como realizar a marcação dos pontos em tempo real.

Comment: Você está usando a primeira ou a segunda versão do kinect?

Comment: A primeira. Utilizo o Kinect SDK 1.8 @pmargreff